# Linux start screen and run a java program and detach it?

Tags: linux, shell-script, process, gnu-screen, java

I have the following script that should do the following:

1. Stop screen "server" if exists
2. Start screen "server"
3. Run a java program and detach screen.

However, when I firstly run the script, the program starts. But if I run it again, it does not restart it.

```
:set fileformat=unix
#!/bin/sh
screen -S server -X quit; 
screen -dmS server; 
cd ~/cadesim-monomer; 
java -jar CadeServerEngine.jar;
```

What did I do wrong? CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

> screen -RD server -X quit

The -RD options force your script to takeover the screen session even if another process is attached to it.